# Association between actors in use case

Tags: uml, use-case

consider in a supermarket system , there is two actors : Customer and Clerk. To create the order , the customer interacts with the clerk and the clerk creates the order in the system. So my question is it valid to do the following use case : 
[image]

In more details , is it valid in uml use case to make an association between two actors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a valid use case diagram. Actors interact with use cases and not with other actors.

Alternatives:

- `Clerk` is associated with `Create order` and you do not show the `Customer`, because the customer does not interact with the software. You can of course mention the customer in the UC narrative or in a comment.
- `Customer` is associated with `Order`, and the system under consideration is no longer your software, but the organizational system composed of the staff, software and equipment the customer is interacting with.
- `Customer` and `Clerk` are both associated with `Create order`, since the `Customer` is involved in the use case, even if it’s indirectly.

Personally, I’d opt for the first approach for the software, because the real users matter the most.   Probably I’d have used the second approach before even starting to think about the software, in the context of the business engineering (Jacobson wrote a nice book, “the object advantage”, in which he proposed to apply use cases to business engineering).

Comment: I'd guess it's the point of view which to choose. I'd probably connect both to the UC the primary (which ever of both that  might be) to the left and the other to the right. I have a conventions (per project) about the primary/secondary being l/r (which is common) or using a `<<use>>` for the secondary.

Comment: Ah, of course Clerk is primary since he actually creates the order...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Christophe's answer:

p. 645 of UML 2.5:

> An Actor can only have Associations to UseCases, Components, and Classes. Furthermore these Associations must be binary.